# Evaluating file at runtime in Racket

Tags: racket, eval

I am making an application using Racket in which Racket is also used as a scripting language. I want users to write scripts utilizing some structs and procedures provided in my executable.

For example I have `userruntime.rkt`:

```lisp
(struct result (x y z))
(provide (all-from-out racket/base))
(provide (struct-out result))
```

And user writes `script.rkt`:

```lisp
(define (my-even? x)
  (if (eq? x 0) #t
                (not (my-odd? (sub1 x)))))

(define (my-odd? x)
  (not (my-even? (sub1 x))))

(result (my-odd? 1) (my-odd? 2) (my-odd? 3))
```

I want to evaluate to the following result (you get the idea):

```lisp
'(#<void> #<void> (result #t #f #t))
```

It seems that `make-module-evaluator` in `racket/sandbox` satisfies my needs. However I failed to find a way to pass the module (as a file compiled and linked in the final executable). The official documentation gives the following example:

```lisp
(define base-module-eval
    (make-evaluator 'racket/base '(define (f) later)
                                 '(define later 5)))
```

Which is not requiring a file. When I try:

```lisp
(make-module-evaluator "userruntime.rkt")  ; make-module-evaluator: expecting a `module' program; got userruntime.rkt [,bt for context]
;; or
(make-module-evaluator 'userruntime)  ; make-module-evaluator: expecting a `module' program; got userruntime[,bt for context]
```

How do I refer to the module in the file correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the `module-decl` arguments to `make-module-evaluator` are strings, they're treated as the code to evaluate. You have to pass a [path](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pathutils.html) to have it treated as a file to read from (Or an open input port ( Personally, I find [`make-evaluator`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Sandboxed_Evaluation.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsandbox..rkt%29._make-evaluator%29%29) easier to work with, but it has the same requirements for its `input-program` arguments.)

Also, your `script.rkt` has an infinite loop in its function definitions, you shouldn't use `eq?` to compare numbers, and the evaluated code doesn't have its toplevel values printed out the way the REPL does - better to wrap the code in a function and call that.

With this `userruntime.rkt`:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
(provide (struct-out result))
(struct result (x y z) #:transparent)
```

and this fixed `script.rkt`:

```lisp
(define (my-even? x)
  (if (= x 0)
      #t
      (my-odd? (sub1 x))))

(define (my-odd? x)
  (if (= x 0)
      #f
      (my-even? (sub1 x))))

(define (callback)
  (result (my-odd? 1) (my-odd? 2) (my-odd? 3)))
```

this code works:

```lisp
(define evaluator
  (make-evaluator 'racket/base (string->path "script.rkt")
                  #:requires '("userruntime.rkt")))
(println (evaluator '(callback))) ; (result #t #f #t)
```

---

Since `make-module-evaluator` requires a module to load, not arbitrary code, one way to use it would be to change `script.rkt` to:

```lisp
#lang racket/base
(require "userruntime.rkt")
(define (my-even? x)
  (if (= x 0)
      #t
      (my-odd? (sub1 x))))

(define (my-odd? x)
  (if (= x 0)
      #f
      (my-even? (sub1 x))))

(define (callback)
  (result (my-odd? 1) (my-odd? 2) (my-odd? 3)))
```

after which

```lisp
(define evaluator
  (make-module-evaluator (string->path "script.rkt")
                         #:allow-for-require '("userruntime.rkt")))
(println (evaluator '(callback)))
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response! However some issue still persists: A) Interpret your code using `racket main.rkt` (the define evaluator file) works. However `raco exe main.rkt && ./main` reports error `standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found for module path: racket/base/lang/reader`. B) I really want the `callback` function be transparent to the user. Is this possible?

Comment: @xiaoyu2006 I've never used `raco exe`. Maybe it doesn't include modules that aren't used at compile time? -- You can try writing a baby REPL - `read` an expression at a time from the source script and evaluate it and capture the return value for printing or whatever.